# PDF File upload using JAVA

Tags: java, pdf, file-upload

just 3 days ago I am getting the following error message when I am trying to upload a PDF file... not sure why it is not working now.... I haven´t changed anything, could it be the server?

This is the error I am getting :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
```

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /drawingUp.jsp:48

45:         File savedFile = new File(folder +"/IngDemo/drawings/"+saveFile) ;
46:         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(savedFile); 
47:         //FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(savedFile);
48:         fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
49:         fileOut.flush();
50:         fileOut.close();
```

Any clues of what it could be would be appreciated.....
Thanks

This is more of the code:

```
String contentType = request.getContentType();
//here we are checking the content type is not equal to Null and
 //as well as the passed data from multipart/form-data is greater than or
 //equal to 0
if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0))
 {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    //we are taking the length of Content type data
    int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
    byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
    int byteRead = 0;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    //this loop converting the uploaded file into byte code
    while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
        byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
        totalBytesRead += byteRead;
        }
    String file = new String(dataBytes);
    //for saving the file name
    String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
    saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
    int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
    String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
    int pos;
    //extracting the index of file 
    pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
    int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
    int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
    int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
    // creating a new file with the same name and writing the 
//content in new file
    String folder = (String) new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")).getParent();
    folder= (String)folder.replace(File.separatorChar, '/');
    File savedFile = new File(folder +"/IngDemo/drawings/"+saveFile) ;
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(savedFile); 
    //FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(savedFile);
    fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Not sure whose code you're showing... the obvious question is where did startPos and endPos come from.  One or both are invalid.

Comment: I have added more of code, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are endPos and startPos being calculated? Your problem is almost certainly that one or both of these values is incorrect.

Comment: I have added more of the code, could you please check? I cannot see anything wrong..

Comment: Please format your code using the "code" button in the editor, so that it is readable.

Comment: I honestly am not sure what all that business with substring detection etc is trying to achieve. I'd strongly recommend scrapping your code and using Apache Commons FileUpload (http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) -- it solves all the parsing problems and has a simple, robust API.

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes a number of things about the request: that it contains a certain number of newlines, the placement of the `=` character, etc. It's best to add checks to your code to make sure that `end > start`, that the assumptions hold true, etc., as the sudden appearance of errors shows you.

Comment: Matt, you mean adding a codition if before the end - start is taking place?